# File not visible in terminal or browser, Caja works fine

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, gif, gnome-terminal

I have a bunch of .gif files that I want to script to put into markdown documents, which will then be compiled to html.

I can find the gif in caja, and open it and it opens fine in Eye Of Mate.  if I open up the directory in a terminal and ls-l it all shows up.  but any time I try to access the file through the terminal it comes up as "file does not exist", this includes chmod and chown:

```bash
isaak@Precision-M4400:~/Documents/Geist/mkdocsExample/docs/1$ ls
1.gif  1.html  1.md  ﻿1.png  ﻿1.sh  ﻿1.txt  1.zip
isaak@Precision-M4400:~/Documents/Geist/mkdocsExample/docs/1$ chmod 777 1.gif
chmod: cannot access '1.gif': No such file or directory
isaak@Precision-M4400:~/Documents/Geist/mkdocsExample/docs/1$ chmod 775 1.gif
chmod: cannot access '1.gif': No such file or directory
isaak@Precision-M4400:~/Documents/Geist/mkdocsExample/docs/1$ ls -l
total 11500
-rw-rw-r-- 1 isaak isaak 5894206 Feb 15 16:46 ﻿1.gif
-rwxrwxrwx 1 isaak isaak     123 Feb 17 10:46 1.html
-rwxrwxrwx 1 isaak isaak     112 Feb 16 16:46 1.md
-rw-rw-r-- 1 isaak isaak    1008 Feb 15 16:46 ﻿1.png
-rwxrw-r-- 1 isaak isaak     416 Feb 15 16:46 ﻿1.sh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 isaak isaak      88 Feb 15 16:46 ﻿1.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 isaak isaak 5856466 Feb 17 10:24 1.zip
```

and while I can open the gif in any image editor I like, running eom 1.gif from a terminal results in the same "file not found" error.

I feel like i must be missing something very stupid, or my system is totally borked.  This problem only exists with these gifs which are auto-generated from FFMPEG out of a 4k video.

Comment: There are probably unprintable characters in the file names.  Try `ls | xxd`

Comment: Try the above command proposed by William Pursell. If that does not work try to use sudo (for example: `sudo chmod 777 1.gif`) and see if that works. If both options do not work, I am guessing there is something wrong with the way permissions are set up on your system.